# WP7.1 txt file handling - Why do I get error "MethodAccessExepction was unhandled"?

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-7.1, text-files, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to create a 2D array of integers that load in data from a .txt file, however when it compiles this line of code: `string line = stream.ReadLine();` it gives me the error in the thread title and also this:

> Attempt to access the method failed, System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String)

I understand there may be differences between using txt files between PC and WP7/360 however I am sure that it's possible because an app my College tutor made used .txt files on his WP7 handset, what sort of changes are there that I must make for Windows Phone to correctly read the file?

For those wanting extra informtion here is the entire method for loading the txt to the int array:

```
    public void loadMap(string mapFileName)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(mapFileName);

        do
        {
            string line = stream.ReadLine();
            string[] numbers = line.Split(',');

            foreach (string e in numbers)
            {
                int tile = int.Parse(e);
                this.tileID[x, y] = tile;

                x++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        while (!stream.EndOfStream);
        xSize = x;
        ySize = y;

        stream.Close();

    }
```

**EDIT**
Makings some progress now although I've hit a new error by using IsolatedStorage methods,
I've added this code before the parsing code:

```
    var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(mapFileName, FileMode.Open, store);
    var stream = new StreamReader(readStream);
```

And now here: `var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(mapFileName, FileMode.Open, store);` I get the error:

> Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743722/how-to-read-in-a-txt-file-in-xna-4-for-windows-phone-7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, applications on Windows Phone are **sandboxed**, which essentially just means that you're prevented from touching things that don't belong to you.  Consider using XNA's `StorageContainer` class instead, which is designed to work around the security limitations inherent to non-PC platforms.

**UPDATE**

On further investigation, it looks like Windows Phone doesn't provide this functionality.  Instead, you should use the `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` class.

Comment: Great thanks :) I'll look into it, after using a StorageContainer the parse code should still be the same right?

Comment: Hmmm, run into another problem, I'm running XNA 4.0 and there is no such thing as the "using Microsoft.Xna.FrameWork.Storage" declaration, something wrong with my XNA install or is there separate frameworks that I have to install?

Comment: Make sure that you've got a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage.dll` in your project.  It should be available through the GAC.

Comment: The one from the 360 references folder? I'm guessing that wp7 can use the same .dll files as the 360 console in some cases?

Comment: My apologies; I didn't realize that this functionality wasn't available on WP7.  See my edit.

Comment: Great thanks, learning a lot about input and output from this, although now I have a new error with my code, updating the question to include my new code

Comment: What's the path that you're trying to load?

Comment: it's a string that's input when calling the method: Map.loadMap("Maps\\map01"); in my Content folder I have a folder called Maps and the file is map01.txt, it's build action is 'Content' and it's Copy to Output Directory action is 'Do not copy'